# Button click event issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```html
<section class="reg" id="reg">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-20">
            <h3>Registration</h3>
             <div class="box-area">
                   <div class="box-area-icon">
                        <div class="heading">           
            <h2>Registration</h2>   
                       <h2><i class="fa fa-users"></i></h2>
                 </div>

                   </div>
                      <table style="width: 100%;" align="center">
                          <tr>
                              <td>Name</td>
                              <td class="text-left">
                                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="vreg_name_txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td>Contacct No.</td>
                              <td class="text-left">
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="vreg_con_txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                              </td>

                          </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td>Email</td>
                              <td class="text-left">
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="vreg_email_txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                               </td>

                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td>State</td>
                              <td class="text-left">
                                  <asp:DropDownList ID="vreg_state_dl" runat="server">
                                      <asp:ListItem>gujrat</asp:ListItem>
                                  </asp:DropDownList>
                              </td>

                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td>City</td>
                              <td class="text-left">
                                  <asp:DropDownList ID="vreg_city_dl" runat="server">
                                      <asp:ListItem>surat</asp:ListItem>
                                  </asp:DropDownList>
                              </td>

                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td>Location</td>
                              <td class="text-left">
                                  <asp:DropDownList ID="vreg_loc_dl" runat="server">
                                      <asp:ListItem>katargam</asp:ListItem>
                                      <asp:ListItem>adajan</asp:ListItem>
                                      <asp:ListItem>piplod</asp:ListItem>
                                      <asp:ListItem>chok</asp:ListItem>
                                  </asp:DropDownList>
                                  <br />
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="vreg_area_txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                              </td>

                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td>Username</td>
                              <td class="text-left">
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="v_user_txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                              </td>

                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td>Password</td>
                              <td class="text-left">
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="v_pass_txt" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                              </td>

                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td class="auto-style2">Confirm password</td>
                              <td class="auto-style3">
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="v_conf_pass_txt" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                              </td>

                          </tr>


                          <tr>
                              <td colspan="2">
                                  <asp:Button ID="reg_btn" runat="server" Text="register" />
                              </td>

                          </tr>


                      </table>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

I am writing a program to insert value in database on button click event. That program is using VB.NET. If I run the application, when I click the button, it does not fire a click event of the button. Help me to correct.  Here's my code:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class main
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Dim command As SqlCommand
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim i As Integer
Dim str As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("con").ConnectionString
Dim con As New SqlConnection(str)

'Protected Sub REGISTER_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles REGISTER.Click

'End Sub

Protected Sub Login_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Login.Click
    If (Page.IsValid) Then

        Dim intusercount As SqlDataReader
        Dim a, b As String
        Using connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-LHSLB8R;Initial Catalog=temp_db;Integrated Security=True")
            Using command As New SqlCommand("SELECT [v_id],[v_name] FROM [vendor_mstr] WHERE [v_user]=@Username AND [v_pass]=@Password", connection)
                command.Parameters.Add("@Username", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = username_txt.Text
                command.Parameters.Add("@Password", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = password_txt.Text
                connection.Open()
                intusercount = command.ExecuteReader
                'Dim red As SqlDataReader =command.ExecuteReader
                If intusercount.HasRows Then
                    While intusercount.Read()
                        MsgBox(intusercount.Item(0))
                        a = intusercount.Item(0)
                        b = intusercount.Item(1)
                    End While
                    Session("uid") = a
                    Session("user") = b
                    Response.Redirect("v_h.aspx")
                Else
                    MsgBox("invalid username or password")
                End If
                connection.Close()
            End Using
        End Using

    End If
   
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Session.Remove("uid")
    Session.Remove("user")

End Sub


Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles reg_btn.Click
    MsgBox("click")
    Try
        con.Open()
        command = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO vendor_mstr(v_name,v_area,v_contact,v_email,v_loc,v_user,v_pass,v_city,v_state)VALUES('" & vreg_name_txt.Text & "','" & vreg_area_txt.Text & "','" & vreg_con_txt.Text & "','" & vreg_email_txt.Text & "','" & vreg_loc_dl.SelectedValue & "','" & v_user_txt.Text & "','" & v_pass_txt.Text & "','" & vreg_city_dl.SelectedValue & "','" & vreg_state_dl.SelectedValue & "')")
        command.Connection = con
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        MsgBox("registered :)")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("not registered :(")
    End Try

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Any error messages or something?

Comment: nothing ..**no response** m getting ..even the same code working on other page..!

Comment: Check if controls names are correct...

Comment: names are correct  only .. login button working properly but register button not responding ..any button m putting on whole page is not wrking

Comment: Would you post your markup?

Comment: you mean asp code?? @moe !!

Comment: script of registration form is added!! @Moe

Comment: Thanks!! BTW I've just tested your code and it worked as expected. You sure the event is not fired? or you were unable to add a database record?

Comment: code was perfect before i did validations..i registered num of record in database..but whn i tried for validation the button din respond..so i removed validations.. but now.. buttons are not responding in whole page.. only login form is working properly !!  m stuck !! :(

Comment: Seems like something is wrong with your HTML. break it down, go to each line and make sure control id's are unique and everything is correct.

Comment: hey i got the problem.. i dont know how to fix..the thing is i hv applied required field in log in ..i wrote in that text box and then tried registration..it worked.. how to separate them..!

Comment: Add a validation group. google asp.net validation group. Or add CausesValidation="False" to your button <asp:Button ID="reg_btn" runat="server" Text="register" CausesValidation="False" />

Comment: tysm ..nd sorry have taken so much of your time

Comment: No problem. Don't forget what download has mentioned about the SQL injection and the parameterized query.

Answer (score 0):

change This

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles reg_btn.Click
```

with this :

```
 Protected Sub reg_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles reg_btn.Click
```

Comment: but it will not insert value in database

Comment: the thing is button click event not responding..not even printing "hiee" msg  in response

Comment: added !!  check it plz

Comment: tried .. :( still not wrking ..! i did validations on all the text box ..after that the buttons are not responding..  shd i make new page?

Comment: yes try to create a new page and write the same code